# Is it wise to dispose of my DBContext object before page render?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, dbcontext

I am using DBContext extensivly in my asp.net web site project.  What I typically do is I have an instance of the dbcontext that is available to the page class and I instantiate that on page load and use it throughout the code, I am not disposing of it however.  Would it be wise for me to use the Pre_Render event on the page to dispose of the dbcontext (I would assume that it is done being used at that point?)

Thanks for any tips.

**SOLUTION**

So I ended up writing a little extension class for my Dotnetnuke modules that handles my dbcontext for me, seems to work good, but I have only rolled it out in a few modules so far.

```
public class ModuleExt : PortalModuleBase
{
    private BPEntities _ent;
    public BPEntities ent 
    {
        get{
            if (_ent == null)
            {
                _ent = new BPEntities();
            }
            return _ent;
        }
    }
    protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ent.Dispose();
    }
}
```

This will enable me to just go ahead an use the ent object (my DBContext) and not worry about disposing as it is done for me on pre render.

Comment: Your solution really needs to be left as an answer and accepted if it's the actual answer. Questions and answers are supposed to be separate on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may certainly do that, if you wish, but you'll need to keep one thing in mind: If you ever, at any point, want to reference a child object/collection from that object you'll need to make sure that it's hydrated before you dispose of the context. Otherwise, you will get a exception telling you that the context has been disposed already.

Some people will say to just have a single context through the application, and that is certainly a valid approach as well, but I much prefer what you're doing right now. I don't like having database connections open all of the time.

Comment: Cool, All of my classes extend the same base class (I am working with DotNetNuke modules) so I wrote a quickie extension class for the module base class (see above)